# C++ Unit Test with Diff on Files

Tags: c++, unit-testing

Is there any library that allows you to diff files in C++ unit tests? Ideally this would work with Boost Unit tests.

I was thinking of a function along the lines of:

```
CHECK_FILES_EQUAL('output.txt', 'reference.txt');
```

Which would then fail the test if the files were equal (possibly showing the line that it failed on).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want something more intelligent that just checking if the files equal byte-by-byte. I would use [google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/), a powerful library which can (among other functionality) calculate a diff between two files. A C++ implementation is available, along with other languages. You'll need to handle file IO yourself, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ApprovalTests](https://approvaltests.com/) to create tests which compare some output file to some approved output. If they differ it can display it in a diff tool e.g. kdiff, and you can choose to accept the changes and update your approved output or reject the test.

Answer (score 0):

Well behaving unit test should not write anything in filesystem. If you are using STL streams then you should use abstraction `std::ostream` and then when testing feed `std::ostringstream` in place of this abstraction.

Just read whole file into a string and compare it.
GTest will notice large strings and will print proper diff.

[Some demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z6sTYvvYb)